# Could a Mimic mimic a Simulacrum?

Tags: dnd-5e, simulacrum, mimic

So, a Mimic can mimic inanimate objects through it's Shapechanger trait:

> The mimic can use its action to polymorph into an object or back into its true, amorphous form. Its statistics are the same in each form. Any equipment it is wearing or carrying isn 't transformed. It reverts to its true form if it dies.

This means that it can't polymorph into creatures, however, a Simulacrum is not a creature, it is an illusion/duplicate.

**Has there ever been a final ruling on this?**

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, what makes you believe that an illusion is an object? If I saw a mirage or started hallucinating, (when I regained coherent thought) I wouldn't consider those things to be objects - they occupy no physical space...

Comment: Related: [Does True Polymorph on a Simulacrum treat it as an object or a creature?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/115619)

Comment: Would that make it a... simimicrum?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## A simulacrum is a creature and thus cannot be mimicked

You say "a Simulacrum is not a creature" but that is not correct. If you look in the spell description *simulacrum* says:

> You shape an illusory duplicate.... **The duplicate is a creature**,
> partially real and formed from ice or snow, and it can take actions
> and otherwise **be affected as a normal creature**.

The mimic's Shapechanger trait says:

> The mimic can use its action to polymorph into **an object**...

Creatures are creatures and not objects - they are mutually exclusive.

Since the spell says the duplicate is a creature, a mimic cannot mimic it.

Comment: I believe "Polymorph" is lower case in the original quote. Roll20 just capitalizes random things

Comment: @DavidCoffron: you are correct! fixed and thanks.

Comment: Thanks.. I'm not at my best today, it seems. Can't believe I read right over that.

Comment: @SeraphsWrath: No worries! If you hadn't asked it, someone else eventually would have I'm sure. :)

Comment: dndbeyond, even without an account, has more accurate rules text than roll20 in my experience.

Comment: @Marq Yeah... the problem is, if you want most things, you have to pay to get 'em. I think the Roll20 Compendium pays so that it can show PHB and MM stuff, which makes it more useful for a quick reference, while Beyond is definitely more useful for someone who references a large amount of material very often.

Comment: @SeraphsWrath: Anything accessible for free on Roll20 is also accessible for free on D&D Beyond. (The only free 5e content on Roll20 is the stuff in the [SRD](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd), which hasn't been updated since 2015. DDB has the licenses for some freely-released official content that Roll20 doesn't share for free, such as content in the [Basic Rules](https://dnd.wizards.com/what-is-dnd/basic-rules) that isn't in the SRD, and the content in the [EEPC](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/player%E2%80%99s-companion).)